# Scanning, group and count file extensions on Linux

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, debian, ubuntu-14.04

Is there a way to scan a path and group and count the file extensions?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146760/count-files-in-a-directory-by-extension

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can use this command -

`ls -ls | awk '{print $10}' | grep "\." | awk -F. '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c`

which count the extensions in the current path.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to count files

To count how many files for each extension are present in a path, you can use one of the answers of *"Count files in a directory by extension"* question of another site<sup>[[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146760/66388)]</sup>, e.g.:

```
ls | awk -F . '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

#### How to list grouped by extension

To group the files by extension you can use simply the `-X` option of `ls`

```
ls -X
```

> ```
> --sort=WORD
>           sort by WORD instead of name: 
>           none -U, extension -X, size -S, time -t, version -v
> ```

**Note**:

- The concept of extension is *imported* from DOS, under Unix there is only the file name eventually with more than one '.' character inside...